# Prepairing list from a django query

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a table where 5 columns are present, lets say col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d, col_e.
In that table I have 20 records. I want to write a django query which will return me 2 separate lists which will contain 20 records each. Lets say I want to pull col_b and col_c from the db, the query should return 2 lists 
for ex:-

```
list_col_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, ....30]
list_col_c = [a, b, c, d, ....t]
```

I know we can do it by pulling both the columns in a django query first and then preparing the list inside a loop. But can we do it in a single instance, without doing any loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach can be used:

```
list_col_b, list_col_c = zip(*MyModel.objects.values_list('col_b', 'col_c'))
```